# How to set up tomcat to use a subdirectory of the application's base directory for the website's resources?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I need to set up a tomcat webapp as follows:

```
webapps/ABC
├── WebContent
│   ├── img
│   │   └── ABC.png
│   ├── ABC.jsp
│   ├── ABCDEF.jsp
│   └── styles
│       └── ABC.css
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ├── model
    │   │   └── ABCData.class
    │   └── servlet
    │       └── ABC.class
    │   └── otherstuff
    │       └── ABChelper.class
    ├── lib
    └── web.xml
```

I managed to get tomcat to show the ABC.jsp-File when accessing [host]/ABC, but within ABC.jsp a number of references to "img/ABC.png" or "styles/ABC.css" and the like exist. I would like to have tomcat automatically look for any Content but .class- or .jar-Files in the "WebContent"-subdirectory. Originally, I'd have preferred a "resources"-subdirectory, but then I read on some website I can't now remember among the plethora of sites I read in the last few hours that the standard apparently is "WebContent"; a standard that doesn't work. Is this in any way possible using only configuration local to the webapp?

Ideally, I'd like to later just create a .jar-File from the webapp root and deploy that to a server.

I tried setting up a local META-INF/context.xml, but that apparently is ignored (no matter what I write into it, tomcat never complains), and -tags in web.xml don't do anything (apart from causing an error if there is a typo in the closing tag).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right if you want to make the resources available to the application when it is deployed they have to be in WebContent or its sub-directories or if you are packing it in a jar to be consumed by other projects put them in the META-INF/resources directory (Servlet 3.0 needed for automatic loading). I think the only thing you might be missing is retrieving them from the context path.

Use something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/styles/ABC.css" />
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/ABC.png" />
```